# React native How to set absolute inside relative?

Tags: react-native

```
class Progress extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={css.top}>
                <View style={css.bar}>
                    <View style={css.brown}</View>
                </View>

            </View>
        );
    }   
}

const css = StyleSheet.create({
    top:{
        backgroundColor:'red',
        width:400,
        height:400,
        padding:100
    }
    bar: {
        flex:1,
        backgroundColor:'yellow',
        position:'relative'
    },
    brown: {
        backgroundColor:'brown',
        position:'absolute',
        top:0,
        left:0,
        width:100,
        height:100,
    },
});
```

[image]

The brown box is supposed to be inside the yellow. But it is out the yellow box. How to fix this? This is react native question

Comment: The brown box _is_ inside the yellow; it's just that the yellow box has a large margin that makes its interior content (the yellow background color) only appear for a small portion of its interior. Try using `padding` instead of `margin`, or consider putting the margin on the red box instead.

Comment: Instead of setting `margin` on bar, try setting `padding` on top. The conflict appears to be using `flex: 1` together with `margin`.

Comment: @Hamms no it's not, padding still got problem.

Comment: @Fawaz its a problem even without flex

Comment: @angrykiwi add a `flex: 1` to `top` and see if that works

Answer (score 0):

The coordinates of your brown area are set to the top left. `top:0,left:0`

You said you wanted to send it in the middle.

```
  brown: {
        backgroundColor:'brown',
        position:'absolute',
        top:"50%",
        left:"50%",
        marginLeft: -50 // your width(100) / 2
        marginRight: -50 // your height(100) /2
        width:100,
        height:100,
    },
```

Comment: @angrykiwi If you come to the center from the current state, you will be inside yellow.

Answer (score 0):

```
  brown: {
    backgroundColor:'brown',
    position:'absolute',
    top:"50%",
    left:"50%",
    right:"50%",
    width:100,
    height:100,
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update your style like this:

```
    bar: {
        flex:1,
        backgroundColor:'yellow',
        position:'relative',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems:'center'
    },
    brown: {
        backgroundColor:'brown',
        position:'absolute',
        width:100,
        height:100,
    },
```